# Overlap SVG in Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, location, overlap

I am trying to put pie charts to show stats about locations on a webpage. However, I am unable to draw the pies over the map. Here is a code example (pies taken from https://danielpataki.com/svg-pie-chart-javascript/)· I would like to put the pie chart between "SW 2nd Ave" and "SW 1st Ave".

I tried to change a bit the tags (e.g. use), but then the pie chart just vanishes.

```js
var height = 0.3 * screen.height,
  width = 16 * height / 9;
var backgroundImage = "https://www.google.com/maps/about/images/mymaps/mymaps-desktop-16x9.png";

var svg = d3.select("#map").attr("width", width).attr("height", height * 0.9);
svg.append("svg:image").attr('xlink:href', backgroundImage).attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);



var data = {
  size: 30,
  sectors: [{
      percentage: 0.45,
      label: 'Thing 1',
      color: "#61C0BF"
    },
    {
      percentage: 0.55,
      label: "Thing Two",
      color: "#DA507A",
    }
  ]
}


sectors = calculateSectors(data);
var newSVG = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', "width: " + data.size + "px; height: " + data.size + "px");
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 0, 'y', 0);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(newSVG)

console.log(sectors)
sectors.map(function(sector) {

  var newSector = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  newSector.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', sector.color);
  newSector.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M' + sector.L + ',' + sector.L + ' L' + sector.L + ',0 A' + sector.L + ',' + sector.L + ' 0 ' + sector.arcSweep + ',1 ' + sector.X + ', ' + sector.Y + ' z');
  newSector.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + sector.R + ', ' + sector.L + ', ' + sector.L + ')');

  newSVG.appendChild(newSector);
})

function calculateSectors(data) {
  var sectors = [];
  var colors = [
    "#61C0BF", "#DA507A", "#BB3D49", "#DB4547"
  ];

  var l = data.size / 2
  var a = 0 // Angle
  var aRad = 0 // Angle in Rad
  var z = 0 // Size z
  var x = 0 // Side x
  var y = 0 // Side y
  var X = 0 // SVG X coordinate
  var Y = 0 // SVG Y coordinate
  var R = 0 // Rotation

  data.sectors.map(function(item, key) {
    a = 360 * item.percentage;
    aCalc = (a > 180) ? 360 - a : a;
    aRad = aCalc * Math.PI / 180;
    z = Math.sqrt(2 * l * l - (2 * l * l * Math.cos(aRad)));
    if (aCalc <= 90) {
      x = l * Math.sin(aRad);
    } else {
      x = l * Math.sin((180 - aCalc) * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    y = Math.sqrt(z * z - x * x);
    Y = y;

    if (a <= 180) {
      X = l + x;
      arcSweep = 0;
    } else {
      X = l - x;
      arcSweep = 1;
    }

    sectors.push({
      percentage: item.percentage,
      label: item.label,
      color: item.color,
      arcSweep: arcSweep,
      L: l,
      X: X,
      Y: Y,
      R: R
    });

    R = R + a;
  })


  return sectors
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="viz" style="text-align:center;">
    <svg id="map">
  
      </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In the CSS for your svg, try changing display to "block"

Comment: This makes no difference unfortunately.

Comment: OK.  Was the only positioning-related SVG experience I have :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the chart to the document body, you should append the chart to the svg holding the map. Then you can position it by changing the 'x' and 'y' attributes.

Also note that as far as I know you can only use one key value pair per call to `Element#setAttributeNS`

```
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 40);
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 160);
document.querySelector("#map").appendChild(newSVG); // select map
```

See this page for more information on svg positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions

```js
var height = 0.3 * screen.height,
  width = 16 * height / 9;
var backgroundImage = "https://www.google.com/maps/about/images/mymaps/mymaps-desktop-16x9.png";

var svg = d3.select("#map").attr("width", width).attr("height", height * 0.9);
svg.append("svg:image").attr('xlink:href', backgroundImage).attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);



var data = {
  size: 30,
  sectors: [{
      percentage: 0.45,
      label: 'Thing 1',
      color: "#61C0BF"
    },
    {
      percentage: 0.55,
      label: "Thing Two",
      color: "#DA507A",
    }
  ]
}


sectors = calculateSectors(data);
var newSVG = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', "width: " + data.size + "px; height: " + data.size + "px");
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 40);
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 140);
document.querySelector("#map").appendChild(newSVG)

console.log(sectors)
sectors.map(function(sector) {

  var newSector = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  newSector.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', sector.color);
  newSector.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M' + sector.L + ',' + sector.L + ' L' + sector.L + ',0 A' + sector.L + ',' + sector.L + ' 0 ' + sector.arcSweep + ',1 ' + sector.X + ', ' + sector.Y + ' z');
  newSector.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + sector.R + ', ' + sector.L + ', ' + sector.L + ')');

  newSVG.appendChild(newSector);
})

function calculateSectors(data) {
  var sectors = [];
  var colors = [
    "#61C0BF", "#DA507A", "#BB3D49", "#DB4547"
  ];

  var l = data.size / 2
  var a = 0 // Angle
  var aRad = 0 // Angle in Rad
  var z = 0 // Size z
  var x = 0 // Side x
  var y = 0 // Side y
  var X = 0 // SVG X coordinate
  var Y = 0 // SVG Y coordinate
  var R = 0 // Rotation

  data.sectors.map(function(item, key) {
    a = 360 * item.percentage;
    aCalc = (a > 180) ? 360 - a : a;
    aRad = aCalc * Math.PI / 180;
    z = Math.sqrt(2 * l * l - (2 * l * l * Math.cos(aRad)));
    if (aCalc <= 90) {
      x = l * Math.sin(aRad);
    } else {
      x = l * Math.sin((180 - aCalc) * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    y = Math.sqrt(z * z - x * x);
    Y = y;

    if (a <= 180) {
      X = l + x;
      arcSweep = 0;
    } else {
      X = l - x;
      arcSweep = 1;
    }

    sectors.push({
      percentage: item.percentage,
      label: item.label,
      color: item.color,
      arcSweep: arcSweep,
      L: l,
      X: X,
      Y: Y,
      R: R
    });

    R = R + a;
  })


  return sectors
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="viz" style="text-align:center;">
    <svg id="map">
  
      </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the answer! You are right for the one attribute per line as well.

Comment: By the way, make sure you take care as to what order you add your svg's/drawable stuff to your map container. Here's a neat resource I found that explains relative positioning with nested svgs. 
Typically this is more idiomatic than using css. 
https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/mimic-relative-positioning-in-svg/